# WebView not showing in Pivot, C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `Pivot` in a `Grid` with 3 tabs, but the URL as source is not showing up when I run the application for 2 of my `WebView`s (the 3rd has not yet been configured). When I take the `WebView` out of my `Pivot` and put it in the `Grid` only, it shows fine.

**My `xaml` file:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Study_Bot.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Study_Bot"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1270">
        <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Title="" Margin="0,312,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="388" Width="1138">
            <Pivot.RightHeader>
                <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Previous" Click="BackButton_Click"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Next" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
                </CommandBar>
            </Pivot.RightHeader>
            <PivotItem Header="Encyclopedia">
                <!--Pivot content goes here-->
                <WebView x:Name="encyclopedia" Source="https://www.britannica.com/search?query=virus" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Journals">
                <!--Pivot content goes here-->
                <WebView x:Name="journals" Source="http://search.sciencemag.org/?searchTerm=virus&amp;order=tfidf&amp;limit=textFields&amp;pageSize=10&amp;&amp;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="News / Blogs">
                <!--Pivot content goes here-->
                <WebView x:Name="newsBlogs"  />
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**My `xaml.cs` file:**

```
namespace Study_Bot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rootPivot.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                // If not at the first item, go back to the previous one.
                rootPivot.SelectedIndex -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // The first PivotItem is selected, so loop around to the last item.
                rootPivot.SelectedIndex = rootPivot.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }

        private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rootPivot.SelectedIndex < rootPivot.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                // If not at the last item, go to the next one.
                rootPivot.SelectedIndex += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // The last PivotItem is selected, so loop around to the first item.
                rootPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding when you fix the height and width of your pivot, so why you align it center or top because it already capture grid according to margin, and if you are not stretch its vertical and horizontal alignment within the grid, this will take space only upto defined for internal elements and webview height width is not fixed so.

```
<Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Title="" Margin="0,312,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="388" Width="1138">
```

that's all or alternately remove horizontal and vertical alignment.

***Note: in your app the way you put margin, height and width this will cause problems relating to screen size and adaptiveness in short your app elements will not adjust or resize according to screen size e.g PC,Tablet or Mobile**